# Tkinter Gui does not appear

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to learning Python following a video Tutorial found on You Tube.
The version of Python is 2.6.4 and the OS is Windows 10 64.bit.

Yesterday the tutorial face the creation of GUI.

The miminum instracion set is in a file:

```
   from Tkinter import *
   top = Tk()
```

Running this file in the Python shell of Windows a little window appares.
Yestreday all was running correctly.
The tutorial adds labels and button.

Today I restarted but running the same example the window does not apper.

Could you help me to understand what is wrong?
Ther are some process open?
I have to to some kind of restet.

Thank you

Comment: On a side note: why are you running Python 2.6.4? Why not 2.7.x or Python 3? If you are just starting to learn Python, I'ld recommend Python 3, since Python 2.7.x will retire next year... (unless the course you are following requires Python 2).

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer: You basically say that something unknown changed and then things ceased to work. You need to be more specific for a good question. However, in the long run, using version control (like e.g. git) will help you retrace your steps and thus allow you to answer such questions yourself.

Comment: @Niels Henkens: because the video tutorial use Python 2.6.4. It is a bit old but is complete and in my language. In the video tutorial the instruction mainloop() is not used and yesterday witout this instruction my program was running correctly

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I can perfectly unserstand your comment but yesterday the program was working without the mainloop. The right question is why Yesterday the code was running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to start the Tkinter GUI. You should add `.mainloop()` for that. So:

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()
top.mainloop()
```